# Export only some of the fields using Angular2Csv

Tags: angular

I am using [Angular2Csv](https://github.com/javiertelioz/angular2-csv) for exporting JSON result data to CSV. But it is exporting all the fields. Is it possible to export only specific fields with out filtering the data?

```
 exportToCSV = function (dataobj) {
    const options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: true,
      headers: Object.keys(dataobj.data[0]),
      // headers: ['API Id', 'RRN', 'Test Case Group', 'Test Case Id', 'Description', 'Institution id']
    };
    new Angular2Csv(dataobj.data, 'My Report', options);
  };
```

Comment: You can use,  `Object.keys(dataobj.data[0]).filter(a=> a!== 'ignoring keys');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  to filter out your headers and data;

```js
const exportToCSV = function (dataobj) {debugger;
    const ignoreHeaders = ["test1"];
    const options = {
      fieldSeparator: ',',
      quoteStrings: '"',
      decimalseparator: '.',
      showLabels: true,
      showTitle: true,
      headers: Object.keys(dataobj[0]).filter(a=> ignoreHeaders.indexOf(a)===-1),
      // headers: ['API Id', 'RRN', 'Test Case Group', 'Test Case Id', 'Description', 'Institution id']
    };
    var data= dataobj.map(a=>{
      return options.headers.map(b=>{
         return a[b];
      })
    })
    console.log(options.headers)
    console.log(data);
    
    
  };
  
  exportToCSV([{"test1":"1","test2":"2","test3":"3"},{"test1":"1","test2":"2","test3":"3"},{"test1":"1","test2":"2","test3":"3"}]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there any option like `keys: ['test1', test2' ]`

Comment: Can you please explain more about this options?

Comment: I tried but still i am able to see the field which i do not want. can you please help on that

Comment: I want to remove key and value from the JSON and finally uploaded to CSV, But here i am able to remove only `key` but not value.

Comment: Can you post what you are getting in `dataobj.data[0]`?

Comment: i am getting only keys from the dataobj.data[0]. `["tes1", "test2", "test3"]`

Comment: This should work as expected, I don't have any idea what you are talking about, Edit your question and explain with example

Comment: Thanks @just code. it is working fine.  But one of the field value showing like `3.53012E+15`. can you please help on this. But the actual value is, `3530123456789010`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object resource that only contains attributes from `dataobj` you want to download => 'API Id', 'RRN', 'Test Case Group', 'Test Case Id', 'Description', 'Institution id' and push the values from your original `dataobj` object, to the new one like so:

```
this.myData=  new Array<dataObjDownload>();
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

  this.myData.push
  ({aPIId: this.data[i].aPIId,
    rRN: this.data[i].rRN,
    testCaseGroup: this.data[i].testCaseGroup,
    testCaseId: this.data[i].testCaseId,
    description: this.data[i].description,
    Institutionid: this.data[i].Institutionid,
  });
}
```